# SQL UNION two tables with different column names

Tags: sql, union

How do I union two tables where their are columns that have different names in the two tables. Table1 has the column name 'Measure'; the data that matches this in Table2 has the column name 'Metric'.

I have tried the following but it returns zero results when I run the query:

```
CREATE VIEW `Dataset.Combined_Table` AS (                                
SELECT
Date, Account, Measure

FROM
`Dataset.Table1` 

UNION ALL

SELECT Date, Account, Metric Measure

FROM `Dataset.Table2` )
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stacking two sql tables (2008) with different column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10452412/stacking-two-sql-tables-2008-with-different-column-names)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic in your query looks fine.  I question the back ticks and the parentheses are not needed.  Does this do what you need?

```
CREATE VIEW Dataset.Combined_Table AS                                
    SELECT Date, Account, Measure
    FROM Dataset.Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Date, Account, Metric as Measure
    FROM Dataset.Table2;
```

Comment: I was just about to type that.  Just use an alias on the second query column.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this without the "Metric as Measure" portion and found no issue.

Source: Northwind sample template.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e

```
SELECT [Order Date]
FROM [Product Orders]

UNION

SELECT [Creation Date]
FROM [Product Purchases]

ORDER BY [Order Date]
```